# Using mootools with Windows 8 Metro JavaScript App

Tags: validation, windows-8, mootools, windows-store-apps

I'm using **mootools-core-1.4.5.js** in a **Windows 8 Metro JavaScript App**, and when a try to **Create App Packages**, I got an error at the **Validation** step :

```
mootools-core-1.4.5.js has JavaScript syntax or other problems.
```

Comment: We don't have enough information to help you.  Try stripping away pieces of your application until you have the smallest reproducible example.  Once you have that, we will be better able to help you.

Comment: Thanks, I already found a solution

Comment: Good find!  That should help other people too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that works for me. 
I used **mootools-core-1.4.5-full-compat.js** and I commented out these lines :

```
//Browser.exec = function(text){
//  if (!text) return text;
//  if (window.execScript){
//      window.execScript(text);
//  } else {
//      var script = document.createElement('script');
//      script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
//      script.text = text;
//      document.head.appendChild(script);
//      document.head.removeChild(script);
//  }
//  return text;
//};

//String.implement('stripScripts', function(exec){
//  var scripts = '';
//  var text = this.replace(/<script[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)<\/script>/gi, function(all, code){
//      scripts += code + '\n';
//      return '';
//  });
//  if (exec === true) Browser.exec(scripts);
//  else if (typeOf(exec) == 'function') exec(scripts, text);
//  return text;
//});
```